# Resolve instance which implement multiple interfaces from Unity Container

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

Please see my current code below

```
public interface ICoach
    {
        void Test();
    }

    public class Player : IPlayer
    {
        void IPlayer.Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.Name + "Run");
        }

        void IPlayer.Jump()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.Name + ": Jump");
        }

        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }


        public Player(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }

    public class Coach : ICoach
    {
        void ICoach.Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
        }
    }

    public class SuperPlayer : ICoach, IPlayer
    {
        private int count = 0;

        public void Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Super player test");
            count++;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Super player run");
            count++;
        }

        public void Jump()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Super player jump");
            count++;
        }

        public void PrintRunTimes()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Super player runs {0} times", count));
        }
    }

container.RegisterType<IPlayer, Player>();
container.RegisterType<ICoach, Coach>();
container.RegisterType<ICoach, SuperPlayer>("super", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IPlayer, SuperPlayer>("super", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

The SuperPlayer class implement two interfaces: IPlayer and ICoach; the Player class implement IPlayer interfaces and the Coach class implement ICoach interafce.

I can resolve a SuperPlayer instance with the super parameter. But it is singleton. If I don't register like this,resolving from IPlayer and ICoach with super parameter will return 2 difference instances. Is there a way to resolve an SuperPlayer instance, not a singleton instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new `ISuperPlayer` interface that combines `ICoach` & `IPlayer`. Then implement, register, and resolve that interface as required.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that's not my question. I know ContainerControlledLifetimeManager make it as singleton, but with your solution, when I resolve from ICoach and IPlayer, the instances are two different. My SuperPlayer implements both 2 interfaces. I want to resolve a SuperPlayer witch contains all of the methods in ICoach and IPlayer. thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not really sure what you're asking. If you e.g. resolve `ICoach` the type will always be `ICoach` and therefore won't have any `IPlayer` methods. You could cast to a `SuperPlayer` with something like `var superPlayer = container.Resolve<ICoach>("super") as SuperPlayer;`. Alternatively, you can resolve a `SuperPlayer` directly with `var SuperPlayer = container.Resolve<SuperPlayer>();`. Or you could create a new `ISuperPlayer` interface that combines `ICoach` & `IPlayer`, then register and resolve that. Sorry I can't give more help but I'm not sure what you need.

Comment: "Or you could create a new ISuperPlayer interface that combines ICoach & IPlayer, then register and resolve that. " This should be a good solution for me. Thanks!

Comment: you can update your answer and I will mark it as solution. Thanks.